# Can't read data from a DB in a nextJS/Firebase app

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-realtime-database

I am having the problem hereafter within a nextJS app that I created on Firebase.

I have some data stored in a realtime DB and I want to make a component to read it.

This is my firebase/config.js :

```
import {initializeApp} from "firebase/app";
import {getDatabase} from "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WEB_API_KEY,
    databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID,
  };

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const firebaseDatabase = getDatabase(firebaseApp);
```

I previously used this configuration to write the data to the DB.

And this is the component I am trying to make to read the data:

```
import {firebaseDatabase} from '../../firebase/config';
// (Changed) import {ref} from "firebase/database";
import {onValue,ref} from "firebase/database";

export default function ShowData() {
  const dbRef = ref(firebaseDatabase, 'Restaurant')

  // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our DB reference:
  /*dbRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  }, (errorObject) => {
    console.log('The read failed: ' + errorObject.name);
  }); 
  */ 


  console.log('Test onValue')
  onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
          console.log(snapshot.val())
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('Error(onValue): '+error);
        }
  );



  return (
        <div>
      <div>ShowData</div>
      {/* ...... */}
        </div>
  )
} /* End of ShowData */
```

The problem is though this error message disapeared with the code changes:

```
Property 'on' does not exist on type 'DatabaseReference'.
```

I still do not see the expected output showing up.

Though I can check that I have 8 items under Restaurant in my DB.

Can someone see what I am doing wrong and how I could solve this issue ?

For testing purpose, I've set my rules as:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you do `import { ref } from "firebase/database";` you use the **modular version** of the JS SDK but your code for listening to the RTDB data is from the **namespaced** JS SDK (prior to V9).

You should then do as follows. More details in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web_value_events).

```js
import { ref, onValue } from "firebase/database"; // <== See onValue

// ...

const dbRef = ref(firebaseDatabase, 'Restaurant')
onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
  // ...
});
```

Note that you may add a [`cancelCallback`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database#onvalue_47c1ae9) to see if there is any error:

```js
onValue(
  dbRef,
  (snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    // ...
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: I already tried the code you suggest but the "console.log(snapshot.val())" does not seem to produce any output in the console.

Comment: It may be because you have some security rules that prevent reading or a typo in the node name (is it "Restaurant"?). You may add a [`cancelCallback`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database#onvalue_47c1ae9) to see if there are any errors.

Comment: I've set my rules to allow all (for testing), see the end of my post (I just updated it).
But I still can't see anything coming out from my code and can't any error either.

Comment: I just found out that I needed to add 'use client'; to my component. Now I can see some output displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing the implementation of Firebase JS SDK Web modular API with Web namespaced API.

Let's say you have the following database structure:

```
{
  "Restaurants": {
    "RestaurantID": {
      "name": "Restaurant Name",
      "rating": 5
    }
  }
}
```

If you wish to listen for any changes in `Restaurants` database or any path, you may use the following:

```
import { firebaseDatabase } from '../firebase/config';
import { ref, onValue } from "firebase/database";

export default function Home() {

  const dbRef = ref(firebaseDatabase, 'Restaurants');
  onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data);
  });

}
```

Note that `onValue` method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes. See this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data) to know the best practices for reading data from Realtime Database.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're facing is due to the fact that you're trying to use the on method on a DatabaseReference object, which doesn't have an on method. Instead, you should use the onValue method from the Firebase SDK.

Here's the corrected code:

```
import { firebaseDatabase } from '../../firebase/config';
import { onValue, ref } from 'firebase/database';

export default function ShowData() {
    const dbRef = ref(firebaseDatabase, 'Restaurant');

    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our DB reference:
    onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('Error(onValue): ' + error);
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <div>ShowData</div>
            {/* ...... */}
        </div>
     );
     } /* End of ShowData */
```

However, keep in mind that this will only log the data to the console. If you want to display the data in your component, you should store the data in a state variable and update the state when the data changes. Here's an example of how you could do that using React hooks:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { firebaseDatabase } from '../../firebase/config';
import { onValue, ref } from 'firebase/database';

export default function ShowData() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const dbRef = ref(firebaseDatabase, 'Restaurant');

        const unsubscribe = onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
            setData(snapshot.val());
        }, (error) => {
            console.log('Error(onValue): ' + error);
        });

        return () => {
            unsubscribe();
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <div>ShowData</div>
            {data && (
                <ul>
                    {Object.entries(data).map
```